# How to compare two directories thoroughly without git?

Tags: files, diff

Here thoroughly means “list all differ files, find those files with same name and different content, list the difference of content”.

Before I got a lazy solution, `git init` one directory and copy another directory into it. Then using `git diff` to view the difference.

But I wonder there is another more smart way to do this? Thus I raised this question.

Comment: You do not need `git init` or copy directories, you can use (at least with the current version of Git) `git diff --no-index`.

Answer (score 10):

`diff -Naur dir1/ dir2/`

Pretty useful for submitting software patches, incidentally: `diff -Naur orig/ patched/ > my_changes.diff`

Comment: Why I got strange stuffs like `����*�����;3[��` when using this command? The compared files containing utf-8 code.

Comment: Try `diff -Naur -U8 dir1/ dir2/`. (That may or may not fix the problem; it could have to do with the codepages in your kernel, how your terminal is set up, the underlying filesystem, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

To complement on the response of @Bandrami, because I had the same problem @Zen did: before `diff`ing the directories, make sure you cleaned all binaries and code unrelated files from `dir2/`, *then* compare the two directories. For instance:

```
$ cd dir2
$ make clean
$ cd ..
$ diff -Naur dir1/ dir2/
```