# Inspecting two directory trees

Tags: directory-structure

How can I inspect two directory trees to determine if they are identical. Are there some good tools that allow tree merging that is free?

I am using Ubuntu Linux 20.04 LTS on an x86_64 architecture.

I am interested in the contents of the files or directories, whether they are identical (in regards to source code or text).

Comment: What to you want to compare? Only file and directory names and contents, or also metdata, and if so which ones (ownership, permissions, timestamps, extended attributes such as ACLs, selinux, etc)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two directories thoroughly without git?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204249/how-to-compare-two-directories-thoroughly-without-git)

Comment: Do you want to merge two directory structures or determine whether they are different?  If you're going to combine them, what does that mean? What happens if there are name collisions?

Comment: Initally I want to determine what is different (I know there are differences).  Then I have to carefully merge them  to get a release out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `diff` Linux command will be sufficient.
Shown below is a structure of folder and sub folders we've created:

[image]

It contains two sub-folders, each with two text files (**file1.txt** and **file2.txt**) to be compared.

**file1.txt** is identical at **folder1** and **folder2**

Using the following, will compare both folders and with all their files:

`diff ./folder1 ./folder2`

The result are (as expected):

[image]

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).